# Can anyone explain to me difference between angular.module('myApp.data') and angular.module('myApp')?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

i want to understand the difference between  `angular.module('myApp.data')` and `angular.module('myApp')`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing complicated here .... these are 2 completely independent modules with different names.

The reference to `'myApp'` in `'myApp.data'` is only done by author as a naming convention to suggest that the module will be used in another module but has no programming importance as far as angular is concerned.

The only way that angular will recognize `angular.module('myApp.data')` is part of `angular.module('myApp')` is by dependency injection when the `myapp` is declared

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.data'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me one more thing suppose I have a method in myApp.data and want myApp to access that data how can I achieve this

Comment: Any component of any module injected into other module is available throughout app